# Display a Window Manager and still be able to press the back button on the phone

Tags: android, flags, android-windowmanager

I am creating a floating view for an app, and I have noticed that there are flags to be used that will enable you to remove or put focus on your views like the `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` and `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` to put focus on your view.

My view contains an edit text I know that using `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` will make it work but it disables the back button of the phone.

How would I be able to make it work that the user can type in the edittext and not disable the back button?

My initial idea is to just do this everytime the user needs to type in the edit text:

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

and then revert the view back to this when not needed:

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Is there any other way a better or more efficient way to this?

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```